# Performing in-line variable substitution for path in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am having difficulties in finding a way to use the input path and set is as the output path for a simple Copy Features tool. I use the substitution by the workspace but it outputs the results into the default ArcGIS folder.

I am not sure how to set the workspace to hold the path of the input feature class. As the input feature class is a parameter, I cannot use a hardcoded path. Please see below:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In the first example, you can [parse](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004000000008000000) the path and call `%Value%`.  In the second example (which may not apply in your case), you can write *intermediate files* to [in_memory workspace-](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000005s000000)-thus, eliminating the need for parsing the path and possibly eliminating the need for the Copy Features tool.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many thanks - This is what I am looking for. but I cannot find the Parse Path tool? How to add it to the model builder?

Comment: Right click on the ModelBuilder screen > Model Only Tools > Parse Path

Comment: To make sure the parse path runs first, connect "Value" to the "Copy Features" tool as a precondition.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Parse Path](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004000000008000000.htm) tool (only available within Model Builder) on the input features, using the 'PATH' option, and name the output 'workspace' to get it to work with your current Copy Features settings.

Comment: Many thanks - This is what I am looking for, but I cannot find the Parse Path tool? How to add it to the model builder? I can easily add other tool, for example, Add Fiel via the Search tab, but not the Parse Path